# Búsqueda dicotómica / Búsqueda binaria

Tags: c

Me han pedido hacer el algoritmo de búsqueda dicotómica o búsqueda binarias.

El caso es que lo tengo hecho per el problema es que no acaba de funcionar correctamente.

Aquí os dejo el algoritmo a ver si me podéis decir por qué intente buscar el número que intente siempre me dice que está en la posición 0.

PD: Solo es el `case7` y la "función 7". He decidido pasar todo el programa porque creo que así se entiende mejor.

Código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define nmax 50

void llegir_vector (int vector [],int num);
void mostrar_vector (int vector [], int num);
int buscar_vector (int vector [], int num, int num_buscar);
int repeticions (int vector [], int num, int num_element);
int posicio_maxima (int vector [], int num);
void bombolla (int vect [], int num);
void dicotomica (int vector [], int num);


    void main () {

        int cont, n, num, i, opcion, res, num_buscar, num_element;  
        int vector[nmax];
        n = 1;

        while (n!=0) {
            printf ("\nSelecciona una opcio: \n");
            printf ("---------------------\n");
            printf ("1.- Introduïr un vector:\n");
            printf ("2.- Mostra el vector per pantalla.\n");
            printf ("3.- Buscar un element en el vector.\n");
            printf ("4.- Comptar quantes vegades apareix el mateix caràcter en el vector.\n");
            printf ("5.- Buscar la posició de l'element més gran del vector.\n");
            printf ("6.- Ordena el vector amb el métode de la bombolla.\n");
            printf ("7.- Busca un element en el vector mitjançant la búsqueda dicotòmica.\n");
            printf ("0.- Sortir del programa.\n");
            printf ("------------------------\n");
            scanf ("%d", &n);

            switch (n) {

                case 1: 
                    system("clear");
                    printf("Introdueix la longitud del vector: ");
                    scanf ("%d", &num);

                    printf ("Introdueix el vector: ");
                    llegir_vector (vector, num);
                    break;

                case 2: 
                    system("clear");
                    mostrar_vector (vector, num);
                    break;

                case 3:
                    system("clear");
                    printf ("Escriu el número a buscar: ");
                    scanf ("%d", &num_buscar);
                    res = buscar_vector(vector, num, num_buscar);

                    if (res == -1){
                        printf ("No s'ha trobat cap.\n");
                    }

                    else {
                        printf ("És la posició: %d\n", res);
                    }   
                    break;

                case 4:
                    system("clear");
                    printf ("Escriu el número que vols comptar les vegades que es repeteix: ");
                    scanf ("%d", &num_element);
                    res = repeticions(vector, num, num_element);
                    printf ("El %d es repeteix %d vegades.\n", num_element, res);
                    break;

                case 5:
                    system("clear");
                    res = posicio_maxima(vector, num);
                    printf ("La posició del element màxim es la posició %d.\n", res);
                    break;

                case 6:
                    system("clear");
                    bombolla (vector, num);
                    printf ("Vector ordenat!!!!!\n");
                    break;

                case 7:
                    system("clear");
                    printf ("Escriu el número a buscar: ");
                    scanf ("%d", &num_buscar);
                    dicotomica (vector, num);

                    if (res == -1){
                        printf ("No s'ha trobat cap.\n");
                    }

                    else {
                        printf ("Si s'ha trobat, està en la posició: %d\n", res);
                    }   
                    break;                                                      
            }
        }    
    }


    // Función número 1.

    void llegir_vector (int vector [],int num) {
        int i;
            for (i = 0; i<num; i++) {
                scanf("%d", &vector[i]);

            }
    }


    // Función número 2.

    void mostrar_vector (int vector [],int num) {
        int i;
            for (i = 0; i<num; i++) {
                printf ("%d ", vector[i]);
            }
    }


    // Función número 3.

    int buscar_vector (int vector [], int num, int num_buscar) {
        int i, cont;
            i = 0;
            while (i < num){
                if (vector[i] == num_buscar){
                    return (i);
                }
                i ++;
            }
        return (- 1);
    }

    // Función número 4.

    int repeticions (int vector [], int num, int num_element) {
        int i, cont_repeticiones;
            i = 0;
            cont_repeticiones = 0;
            while (i < num){
                if (vector[i] == num_element){
                    cont_repeticiones ++;
                }
                i ++;
            }
        return (cont_repeticiones);
    }

    // Función número 5.

    int posicio_maxima (int vector [], int num) {
        int i, max;
            i = 0;
            max = 0;
            while (i < num){
                if (vector[i] > max){
                    max = vector[i];
                }
                i ++;
            }
        return (max);
    }

    //Funciçon número 6.

    void bombolla (int vector [], int num) {
        int i, j, canvi, aux;
            canvi = 1;
            i = 0;
            aux = 0;
            while ( canvi == 1){
                canvi = 0;
                for (j = 0; j <=num-i-2; j++){
                    if (vector[j] > vector[j+1]){
                        aux = vector[j];
                        vector[j] = vector[j+1];
                        vector[j+1] = aux;
                        canvi = 1;
                    }
                }
                i ++;
            }
    }

    //Función número 7.

    void dicotomica (int vector [], int num) {
        int i, izq, der, centro, valor;
        i = 0;
        izq = 0;
        der = num - 1;
        while ((vector[centro] != valor) && (izq < der)) {
            centro = (izq + der) / 2;
            if (vector [centro] < valor) {
                izq = centro + 1 ;
            }
            else {
                der = centro - 1;
            }
            centro = (izq + der) / 2;
        }       
        if (valor == vector [centro]) {
            return (i);
        }
        else {
            return (- 1);   
        }
    }
```

Comment: La función `dicotomica()` retorna el valor de `i`, el cual incializas con cero y luego ya no cambia más en todo el bucle. Creo que lo que deberías retornar es el valor de `centro`, si no lo he entendido mal.

Comment: Gracias por responder, cambié return (i); por return (centro); y sigue el resultado dando 0.

Comment: Que va, no hay manera de que funcione, ya corregí los errores que me dijiste pero al parecer tiene que haber alguno más, pese a que estoy buscando, no encuentro ningún otro.  Gracias por la ayuda.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

He revisado con más detenimiento el código. Había varios errores:

1. La función `dicotomica()` en su declaración retorna `void`, pero debería retornar un entero (la posición en que se encuentra el dato).
2. El entero a retornar no debe ser `i` (que de hecho sobra en esa función pues siempre vale cero), sino `centro`.
3. La función debe recibir como parámetro el número a buscar. De lo contrario ¿cuál es ese `valor` que estamos buscando? No está inicializado. Además, el parámetro `num` tendrá el número de elementos del array. Es decir, esta función tendría el mismo prototipo que la función `buscar_vector()`, pues tiene el mismo cometido aunque lo haga de otra forma.
4. Cuando llamas a `dicotomica()` desde el programa principal, no recoges el valor retornado. Así pues la variable `res` tiene cualquier valor imprevisible y no el resultado de la función.
5. En esa misma llamada, hay que pasarle como parámetros además del vector y de `num`, el dato a buscar.
6. La lógica interna de la propia función `dicotomica()` está mal, pues las variables `izda`, `dcha` y `centro` deben ser inicializadas antes de entrar al bucle.

Corrigiendo todos los fallos anteriores, las modificaciones a realizar en tu programa serían:

```c
// En la zona de prototipos de funciones:
int dicotomica (int vector [], int num, int num_buscar);

// En el case 7 del main:
                case 7:
                    system("clear");
                    printf ("Escriu el número a buscar: ");
                    scanf ("%d", &num_buscar);
                    res = dicotomica (vector, num, num_buscar);

                    if (res == -1){
                        printf ("No s'ha trobat cap.\n");
                    }

                    else {
                        printf ("Si s'ha trobat, està en la posició: %d\n", res);
                    }
                    break;

// En la función dicotomica:

   int dicotomica (int vector [], int num, int valor) {
        int izq, der, centro;
        izq = 0;
        der = num - 1;
        centro = (izq+der)/2;
        while ((vector[centro] != valor) && (izq < der)) {
            if (vector [centro] < valor) {
                izq = centro + 1 ;
            }
            else {
                der = centro - 1;
            }
            centro = (izq + der) / 2;
        }
        if (valor == vector [centro]) {
            return (centro);
        }
        else {
            return (- 1);
        }
    }
```

Comment: @AlexIglesias De nada :-) El "error" es intencionado, ya que dentro de la función el valor que buscabas lo llamabas `valor`, por lo que decidí llamar al parámetro igual, para no tener que renombrarlo todo.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, me ha funcionado.

Solo hay un pequeño fallo, la función debería ser `int dicotomica (int vector [], int num, int num_buscar)`, no `int dicotomica (int vector [], int num, int valor)`, ya que la variable`valor` no existe como tal jeje, no sé ni por qué la puse ahí. De igual forma, la varaible `valor` y la variable `num_buscar` harían la misma función, solo tienen nombre diferente.

De nuevo, gracias por la ayuda, un saludo.

Answer (score 3):

La búsqueda dicotómica llamada también Binaria, es un algoritmo muy eficaz y voraz, ya que reduce el tiempo de busqueda considerablemente siempre y cuando el **`array este ordenado`** previamente.

Este algoritmo es voraz ya que en cada iteracion parte a la mitad el array, comparando si el dato buscado esta en la parte superior o en la parte inferior del array partido, esto por la comparacion al dato central del array.

**Ej:** dato a buscar: 4

`[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]` => array ordenado, inf=`[1,2,3,4,5]`,sup=`[6,7,8,9,10]`
`[1,2,3,4,5]`=> array ordenado, inf=`[1,2,3]`,sup=`[4,5]`
`[4,5]`=> array ordenado, inf=`[4]`,sup=`[5]`
`[4]`=> elemento encontrado

> en caso de no se encontrado se acuerda en retornar un **-1 o false**

**Codigo**

```
int dicotomica(int  vector[], int n, int dato) {
   int centro,inf=0,sup=n-1;
   while(inf<=sup){
      centro=((sup-inf)/2)+inf;
      if(vector[centro]==dato)       
          return centro;
      else 
          if(dato < vector[centro]) 
              sup=centro-1;
          else                           
              inf=centro+1;
   }
   return -1;
}
```

Donde `vector` es el vector de datos,`n` es el tamaño de tu vector y `dato` es el dato a buscar.

Esta funcion esta adecuado a tu `if(res==-1)` y tu mensaje(en catalan):`Si s'ha trobat, està en la posició`, asi que si el dato se encuentra retorna la posicion del dato y si no lo hace retorna -1.

Comment: Lo mismo que le dije a Abulafia va dirigido a ti, muchas gracias por responder, un saludo!